# Ignorar strings que contenham "@" - jquery

Tags: jquery

Vejam a função, abaixo, ela serve para alterar o primeiro caractere da `string` para maiúsculo e os demais caracteres em minusculo, nos campos que possuem `class lower`

Esta função ignora strings menores que 4 caracteres, e agora eu quero que ignore strings que contenham `@`, enfim, que ignore e-mail, e não altere o primeiro caractere para maiúsculo.

Tentei da seguinte forma e não deu.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $.fn.capitalize = function() {
        //palavras para ser ignoradas
  var wordContainAt = "@";
  
        var wordsToIgnore = ["DOS", "DAS", "de", "do"],
            minLength = 3;

        function getWords(str) {
      if (str == undefined) {
    str = "abc def";
   } else {
       str = str;
   }
            return str.match(/\S+\s*/g);
        }
        this.each(function() {
            var words = getWords(this.value);
            $.each(words, function(i, word) {
                // somente continua se a palavra nao estiver na lista de ignorados
                if (words.indexOf(wordContainAt) != -1){
      words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
  } else if (wordsToIgnore.indexOf($.trim(word)) == -1 && $.trim(word).length > minLength) {
                    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
                }
            });
     if (this.value != ""){
               this.value = words.join("");
     }
        });
    };

    //onblur do campo com classe .title
    $('.lower').on('blur', function() {
        $(this).capitalize();
    }).capitalize();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Título</label><br>
<input type="text" class="lower "/>
```

Linha a ser revista:

```
if (words.indexOf(wordContainAt) != -1){
     words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Pelo que vi vc já fez verificando a arroba `@`, certo? Quer que verifique se contenha a palavra `at` também?

Comment: Eu quero verificar somente o `@`, acontece que não está funcionando

Comment: Troque o `words` por `word`: `word.indexOf(wordContainAt)`

Comment: hehe! que mole.. isso mesmo.
Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você não está pegando o valor corretamente passado no laço `.each` no parâmetro `word`:

```
if (words.indexOf(wordContainAt) != -1){
```

O correto seria `word` e não `words`:

```
if (word.indexOf(wordContainAt) != -1){
```

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar se uma string é um email ou não, use essa função:

```
//Verifica se a string é um email
    function isEmail(email) {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        return regex.test(email);
    }
```

Comment: Eu queria colocar tudo numa mesma função.. a que coloquei no exemplo, na verdade, quero que; o que conter "@", continue tudo minusculo